# Entity Framework within a Com Interop Library

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dll, vb6

I'm trying to use my C# Domain DLL with Entity Framework in a VB6 Windows Form application. I can normally call my functions, but when it comes to Entity Framework, the application stops. It complains about the config file. After a while, I found out it was trying to get the config file from VB6 folder (VB6.exe.config) which does not exist. I was supposing that when I used the DLL, it would try reaching the app.config file within the same folder as it is located, but didn't happen. 
Well, I tried creating a new config file with that name (VB6.exe.config), but it didnt work at all. Entity Framework shows an exception inside its structure. It has to do with something like "System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig".

I also noticed that EF has its own configuration files, and I suppose if it is not findind the config file of the DLL I made, it's not findind the EF's config files either.

Has anybody gone through this situation? Any solution for this?

I appreciate your attention,
many thanks

Jose Carlos

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for that. I shouldnt be using the config file in my DLL. So what I did was configuring the EF in-code with the connection string.